# How do I loop over multiple files to extract specific columns and save as separate files?

Tags: linux, string, bash, unix

I have numerous `*.txt` files. I want to extract column 3 and 5 from each of these files and save them as new files keeping their oiginal names with `new_` extension. I have this bash loop below in trying to do this, but doesn't do what I want. Can someone please help me with this?

```
for i in *.txt; do
cut -f 3,5 $i  > /media/owner/new_$i_assembly.txt 
done
```

Comment: If it doesn't  do what you want, what _does_ it do? Or what is wrong with the output?

Comment: @ypnos I get only one file with no data , i.e blank file.

Comment: What is your field delimiter? See `cut -d` option.

Comment: @ypnos It's tab separated

Comment: @ypnos it works for one file, but not when looping thrugh multiple files

Comment: Btw you should try `/media/owner/new_$(basename -s .txt $i)_assembly.txt`

Comment: @ypnos Thank you. How do you extract columns 3 and 5 in tab separated txt file?

Comment: The way you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure and tell Bash explicitly to expand variable `$i`, otherwise it picks up characters you don't want and expands variable `$i_assembly` instead:

```
for i in *.txt; do
   cut -f 3,5 "$i"  > "/media/owner/new_${i}_assembly.txt" 
done
```

If you don't want the extension included in your new name, use parameter expansion `${i%.*}` that removes everything up to the first `.` included, from the end.

```
for i in *.txt; do
   cut -f 3,5 "$i"  > "/media/owner/new_${i%.*}_assembly.txt" 
done
```

If you decide for a different approach that might result in paths, not just filenames (for example: `**/*.txt`), you can use parameter expansion once again to get only the name of your file:

```
for i in **/*.txt; do
   base=${i##*/} 
   base=${base%.*}
   cut -f 3,5 "$i"  > "/media/owner/new_${base}_assembly.txt" 
done
```

---

Also note that **TAB** is the default delimiter for `cut`, you don't need to specify it with the `-d` option:

```
-d, --delimiter=DELIM
      use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple approach:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    cut -d$'\t' -f3,5 "$f" > "/media/owner/new_${f}_assembly.txt" 
done
```

---

In case if there could be possible whitespace(s) except tabs - you may use the following `awk` approach:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    awk '{ print $3,$5 }' OFS='\t' "$f" > "/media/owner/new_${f}_assembly.txt" 
done
```